# new to java : getting unexpected output

Tags: java

i have created 2 java files.
1. **helloWorld.java**
2. inside the folder **p/node.java**

helloWorld.java folder contains the **main function**

```
import p.node;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
public class helloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<node> list = new ArrayList<node>(); //created list of object node
        list.add(new node('a'));
        list.add(new node('b'));
        list.add(new node('c'));
        list.add(new node('g'));
        list.add(new node('k'));
        list.add(new node('o'));

        System.out.println(list.get(2).val);
    }
}
```

2.**node.java**

```
package p;
public class node {
    public static char val;

    public boolean busy = true;


    public  node(char val)
   {
       this.val=val;
   }
}
```

**Expected Output c**
**Actual output o**
please help me , i'm new to java ... Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Remove `static` from `val`. That makes one `val` regardless of the number of `node`(s).

Comment: thank you so much @ElliottFrisch it works!!

Answer (score 3):

you have declared `val` as `static` and `static` members are `created only once`

remove `static` declaration from `node` class

```
package p;
public class node {
    public char val;
    public boolean busy = true;

    public  node(char val) {
       this.val=val;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the word *static* in line 3 in the class *node*, then should it work.

Best regards
Andree